# Staying up to date on jquery UI with git

Tags: git, jquery-ui

I'd like to have a mechanised way to ensure i have the latest jquery-ui and themes to work with in development. I know that the jquery-ui can get pulled from git at:

> https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui.git

but I was disappointed to see that it only comes with the "base" theme. I can get a zip of the latest of a particular build from:

> http://jquery-ui.googlecode.com/files/jquery-ui-themes-1.8.21.zip

But that means the URL changes with each new release and immediately smells like work that I don't want in my mechanised process. Am I missing a trick? Is there a git repo somewhere that has both code and theme? Is there a git repo with the latest themes?

Answer (score 0):

I think that themes are part of the **build** process. There is a file that names themes in the repo at https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/master/build/themes and this appears to be used by **grunt.js** as part of the build process.

Build instructions are given in the readme

https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/master/README.md#building-jquery-ui